# How to deploy grunt app under specific address?

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs

Hey im running my grunt and I am trying to deploy an app under specific base.

http://localhost:9080/#/ -> http://localhost:9080/my-app/#/

I cant force grunt to do it using base or other stuff from doc ...

Comment: What grunt modules do you use? Share some code :)

Comment: You need to create a directory called my-app in your project and store the distribution code there. The grunt-connect base directory should point to the root of your project.